# Can make STL string::c_str() return NULL when it has no string?

Tags: visual-studio, string, visual-c++, stl

My project has legacy library which consider NULL pointer as empty string.

But when I get return data from std::wstring like this,

```
std::wstring strData;
const wchar* pStr = strData.c_str();
ASSERT(NULL == pStr);  // ASSERT!!
```

pStr is not NULL but pointer which wstring point.

Can I make std::string return NULL when it has no string data?
Now I wrap every str member variable like this :

```
const wchar* GetName() {    // I hate this kinds of wrapping function
    if (m_Name.empty())
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    return m_Name.c_str();
}
```

My working environment is
Visual Studio 2008 sp1 in Windows

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since *you only need that new behavior for interacting with that legacy library* and *not in all code* (for example `strlen()` will break if you pass a null pointer into it) your best bet is to use an utility function for providing proper behavior.

Something like you suggested:

```
const wchar* GetStringBody( const std::string& str )
{
    if( str.empty() ) {
         return 0;
    }
    return str.c_str();
}
```

and call it ***where necessary***.

Answer (score 0):

```
template <typename Char_t, typename Traits_t, typename Allocator_t>
inline const Char_t* StrPtr(const std::basic_string<Char_t, Traits_t, Allocator_t>& aString) {
    return (aString.empty() || !aString.front()) ? nullptr : aString.c_str();
}

template <typename Char_t>
inline const Char_t* StrPtr(const Char_t* aString) {
    return (!aString || !*aString) ? nullptr : aString;
}
```

**Use this general functions to convert strings to pointers.** All `NULL` or `empty() / ""` strings return `nullptr` while any 1+ length strings returns the proper pointer.