# Why an empty() std::basic_string c_str() is not nullptr?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, stl, std

*(pondering on a Sunday evening)*

In the functions I write I tend to rely on both `const char*` and templated inline `const std::basic_string<>&` variants of the same string. But I'm really curious why the `c_str()` of an empty string is not a `nullptr`.

Most C++ coders now disregard `const char*` pointers as C code but I see it very C++ as strings are `null` terminated and continuous and will continue to be this way. But if you use custom allocators, then all the code you write with `const std::string&` arguments is pointless *(unless header only)*.

So your real choice *(if you want to be versatile)* is either old-school character pointers or inline templated functions that can support all sorts of `std::basic_string` with custom allocators or traits. This forces you to inline the templated functions as you cannot predict the template arguments upfront correctly.

*Now my question is*: **Why don't empty strings return nullptr for c_str()?** As the lowest common denominator in string functions, especially for read-only access is the `const char*` not the `const std::string&` which is templated hence constrained. Returning a pointer to anything, especially when there's not string assignment made... seems to me as weird.

**Or am I too much of a maniac to do this?** Always worry about both `const char*` and the templated `const std::basic_string<char, ..., ...>&` counterpart. If `std::string().c_str()` where `nullptr`, I wouldn't worry. But I have to guard against empty strings myself as `c_str()` is unreliable on `std::basic_string`s.

***PS**: I know that old school string functions crash when used with null pointers, but one can easily test for a valid pointer and a non-empty first char before using the string anywhere.*

***PPS**: I'm talking here of sane null-terminated strings, not the null-containing pseudo-strings that the `std::basic_string` peculiarly supports.*

**QUESTION REPHRASED**: Why does `std::string().c_str()` point to memory when it should not? It should be `nullptr`. Unlike `std::string().c_str("")` which is an empty string and requires a `\0` trailing it. So it actually points to valid memory. *(If you don't understand how strings/pointers work, don't bother answering. This requires a bit of C-like understanding.)*

Comment: An empty string is a string with no elements. A null pointer isn't a string.

Comment: I'm not sure how a `const char*` is more versatile. Can you explain? In what way does the fact that `std::string` is a template make it more constrained?

Comment: you're thinking in terms of implementation, but an empty string and a nullptr are fundamentally different concepts

Comment: Downvoters please explain.

Comment: The reasons for why it can't return a `nullptr` are illustrated in the answers. But I honestly don't understand your arguments for why it should. For example, what do you mean by *"I have to guard against empty strings myself as c_str() is unreliable on std::basic_strings."* ? In what way is `c_str()` unreliable?

Comment: @bamboon Nothing much to explain, is there? The entire rant can be summed up as, for some bizarre reason, the OP thinks it's easier, more intuitive, more whatever have you, to write `if(s.c_str() != nullptr) { ... }` than `if(!s.empty()) { ... }`. I'd argue that the input argument not being `nullptr` should be a precondition (for functions taking `char const *` arguments) and a well-written string algorithm shouldn't care whether the input is an empty string, it should return the correct result in any case.

Comment: @Praetorian: That sounds more like an answer to the OP's question, than a reason for downvoting it.

Comment: @Benjamin :) Didn't seem like that when I was typing the comment. Anyway, the answers below are more illustrative of why `c_str()` returning `nullptr` to indicate empty string would just be plain wrong.

Comment: Comparing empty `""` strings to unallocated std::strings or null pointers is weird IMO.

Comment: @sftrabbit Write a `StrLen` function. For a simple pointer, it's easy and can be compiled to a lib. For a std::string, you might have different allocators... so it has to be inlined for the compiler to compile it based on usage scenarios. That's the HUGE difference. Adds up in compile times...

Comment: @Praetorian When you use a `std::string` as an argument in a function, you need to inline it and template it, to cover your S for custom allocators *(required to cross DLL boundaries for example)*... like my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994630/can-make-stl-stringc-str-return-null-when-it-has-no-string/20937719 ... While a C-string pointer requires no such thing.

Comment: "But if you use custom allocators, then all the code you write with const std::string& arguments is pointless (unless header only)." This is one of the primary motivations for [string_view](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3762.html), to provide a better `const string&` that is independent of memory allocation details.

Comment: @Casey That's an idea! But I doesn't seem to be in the standard yet. It will save some lines of code if accepted...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) of `std::string` will construct an empty string.

You can't construct a `std::string` object without a corresponding valid C-string. `std::string()` is equivalent to `std::string("")` thus `std::string::c_str()` will always return a valid pointer and should *never* return a null pointer.

Comment: I was just typing a comment to tell you to do this *(post your comment as an answer)*. I like empty and un-explicitly assigned buffers *(like a string)* to be `null`. It might be just a personal preference...

Comment: What about std::string(3, '\0') having the size three !?

Comment: @DieterLücking That's initialized. Easy. --- And I said in my question I very much dislike the possibility to put nulls in std strings.

Answer (score 5):

In the following expression:

```
const char* foo = "";
```

There is an empty string, [but I do not see a null pointer](http://ideone.com/2QPVlR). An empty C string is a `char []` with the `char[0] = '\0'`, that's all.

A null pointer with `const char*` type is a non-existent string.

Comment: Actually this explanation is nice - an 'empty' string stores information, while a null pointer holds no information (besides being null)!

Comment: @DieterLücking It just acts the fact that there is a real memory address assigned to `foo`. Avoid OP to just believe my words if he doubts it.

Answer (score 2):

If an empty string's `c_str` returned `nullptr`, then this would not be valid:

```
const char* str1 = "";
std::string str2 = "";
const char* str2_c = str2.c_str();
assert(strcmp(str1, str2_c) == 0);
```

That seems like a flawed interface to me. Two empty strings should compare equal.

Comment: You obfuscate more than clarify anything

Comment: **What has empty() got to do with empty strings?** By empty std::string I mean unallocated (unassigned). A `""` string means \0 while an empty string means no memory allocated. So a null pointer makes sense.

Comment: @CodeAngry: `std::string` has no state corresponding to "unallocated". And empty string does not mean "no memory allocated", either in reference to c-strings, or c++ strings.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley It should have as I have no assigned anything to it. That's the value of a nullptr for those that understand pointers. It means NOTHING, not EMPTY as in "".

Comment: @CodeAngry `char* s;` may not be equivalent to `char* s = "";` but `string s;` *is* equivalent to `string s = "";`. An `std::string` is always initialized to an empty string.

Comment: @zakinster So `std::string` is by default initialized to "", not an unallocated string?

Comment: @CodeAngry: No it should not. A pointer is a very primitive type, which may or may not point to a string. `std::string` is not, and should not be equivalent to a pointer. `std::string` is a string. It should always be a string. If you want a nullable type, then use a type which is designed to be nullable (i.e. `boost::optional<std::string>`), not a type which is designed to be a string.

Comment: @CodeAngry Indeed, as Benjamin Lindley said, an `std:string` object does not have a state corresponding to "unallocated".

Answer (score 2):

Consider a C Type String (NULL Terminated String)

```
const char * str1 = "";
const char * str2 = nullptr;
```

- The First implementation is a 0 sized NULL terminated array of characters.
- The Second is just a character pointer initialized to NULL.

If `std::string().c_str()` were to return a `nullptr` it would be outright wrong as its a template C++ string equivalent of a NULL terminated 0 sized C String.

Comment: First one points to memory while the second points to nowhere. Huge difference.

Comment: @CodeAngry: Yup. In particular, the first one points to a C string, the second one does not, and `std::string::c_str()` always returns a pointer to a C string. That's why it's named `c_str`. Obviously `c_str` cannot return `nullptr` because that is not a C string.